# How can I escape single quotes from get method in Javascript?

Tags: php

I am passing the form values via get method.
Here is the url parameters.

```
"name='test'&exp=&level=&gender=&city=&sports="
```

While getting the values from get method in javascript, single quote is getting as `%27`. How can I escape it?

while alerting  `$_GET("name")`, it gives `%27test%27`.

Please help

Comment: You don't need to put the quotes when you pass these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use php's urldecode on the value. Docs found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Let me know if that's what you're looking for :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this in javascript

Comment: [decodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) is the javascript version. May ask how you plan to implement this in js?

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
"name='test'&exp=&level=&gender=&city=&sports="
```

To

```
"name=test&exp=&level=&gender=&city=&sports="
```

or

Use:

```
var decoded = unescape(url);
```

or

```
 var decoded =decodeURI(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mystring = mystring.replace(/'/g,"");` to remove `'` character from mystring. you can try `mystring = mystring.replace(/'/g,"/'");` to escape the single quotes of mystring with backslash `/`.

But what I think is you should not make a url like this if there is really no strong(strange though) reason